# how can I redesign the "Editing: Video" page of Open Edx

Tags: openedx

Hello guys currently I am working on open edx I am very new to the Open edx.
I have configured the open edx but I need to do some programmatical changes and I am not very much aware about the environment on which the open edx has made.I need to change the below page
[image]

I am not able to find this page.
any help would be appriciated thank you.

Comment: open edx is built with Django view handlers and Mako templates, so you won't likely find a .html file to edit what appears in that shadowbox.

Comment: What kind of modifications do you want to make? This popup is a [VideoModule](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/video_module/video_module.py) edit view and it is likely generated from [VideoModule](https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/blob/master/common/lib/xmodule/xmodule/video_module/video_xfields.py#L14). Depending on what are you trying to achieve you might need to fork the edx-platform.